# Swiping to Fragment in ViewPager always scrolls to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `Fragment` that I display in my `ViewPager` that has a `View` with some information about a user and below it a `RecyclerView`. The issue is, every time I scroll to that `Fragment`, the page automatically scrolls down to where `RecyclerView` begins and I don't want that to happen. Rather I would want you to scroll to the place where you last left off while browsing the `Fragment`. Here is my attempt:

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_create_white_24dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.tabs.activity.ScrollingFabBehavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

profile.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/profile_header">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/profile_name"/>

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        fresco:roundingBorderColor="@color/white"
        fresco:roundingBorderWidth="10dp"
        fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
        fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
        fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_row"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_below="@id/profile_header"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

     ...Content here...

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rv_posts_feed"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
```